# Prove that the limit $\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{1}{(x-2)^3}$ is infinity using $\epsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{1}{(x-2)^3}=\infty$

Am I allowed to replace this problem with $\lim_{x \to 2}{(x-2)^3}=\frac{1}{\infty}(=0)$

And therefore for $0<|x-2|<\delta$ there is $\delta^3<\epsilon$ so will take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

First note that the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(x-2)^3}$ change sign at $x=2$ so we can suppose that the limit fot $x>2$ and the limit for $x<2$ are different.

For $\lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x)$ chose $N>0$ and consider the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x>2\\
\dfrac{1}{(x-2)^3}>N
\end{cases}
$$
solving we find:
$$\begin{cases}
x>2\\
x<\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{N}}+2
\end{cases}$$
so the solution is $2<x<\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{N}}+2$. This means that, choosing $\epsilon=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{N}}$ we have that:

> for every $N>0$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>N$ if $2<x <2+\epsilon$ .

And this is the definition of an infinite limit form right.

For the limit from left you can do the same, with some attention to the signs.

Comment: So switching the problem as I wrote is a wrong move?

Comment: Switch from $g(x)$ to $\dfrac{1}{g(x)}$ can be done, but in your question there is some confusion about $\epsilon - \delta$ machinery. Note that for an infinite limit we use a **great** number ( so I've used $N$ and not  $\epsilon$,  usually a small number).

Comment: I just pay attention now, the question is worng as the limit from both sides is different

Comment: Yes. My answer shows that the limit from right is $+\infty$. Can you prove that the limit from left is $-\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes it would be the same just that $/epsilon$ will be on the left and with a minus sign

Answer (score 0):

For every $M > 0$, if $0 < |x-2| < 1/M^{1/3}$, then $|x-2|^{-3} > M$.

Loosely speaking:
if $1/\infty = 0$, then $1 = 0\cdot \infty = 0$; hence division by $\infty$ is attached no meaning.